# Generic error revert message

Tags: solidity, dapps, revert

I'm having a problem with a contract I've developed recently. I'm interacting with it using a dapp written using ReactJS. The problem is: when I call a specific function of this contract I'm getting this revert message:

```
{
  "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at module.exports (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/gas/guestimation.js:142:32)",
  "name": "RuntimeError"
}
```

The contract is a little complex so I'm going to include only the code of the function I'm calling.

```js
function createPreorder(
        ItemMarketplaceLib.PreorderCreationParams memory _newPreorder
    ) public itemMarketplaceNeeded {
        isPreorderValid(_newPreorder._hash, _newPreorder._signature);
        ItemMarketplaceLib.Item memory itemToBorrow = itemMarketplace
            .getItemByID(_newPreorder._idItem);
        require(
            itemToBorrow.owner != address(0),
            "There's no ITEM with the ID you requested."
        );
        require(
            itemToBorrow.option == bytes4(bytes("LEND")),
            "This item can't be borrowed. It is meant to be sold"
        );
        require(
            _newPreorder._endDate > _newPreorder._startDate,
            "The ending date must be greater then the starting date."
        );
        require(
            address(erc20TokenFactory) != address(0),
            "Token factory address not set in calendar."
        );

        uint256 durationOfPreorderInDays = (_newPreorder._endDate -
            _newPreorder._startDate) / 1 days;

        require(
            durationOfPreorderInDays < maxNumberOfDaysOfAPreorder,
            "The days requested exceeds the maximum number of days available for a preorder"
        );
        uint256 amountToLock = itemToBorrow.caution +
            (itemToBorrow.price * durationOfPreorderInDays);

        (address collectionOfToken, , , , , , ) = erc20TokenFactory.getToken(
            itemToBorrow.tokenAcceptedAsPayment
        );
        require(
            collectionOfToken != address(0),
            "The collection for this item does not exist. Probably the address of the token factory was not set"
        );
        TokenTemplate tokenTemplate = TokenTemplate(collectionOfToken);
        tokenTemplate.transferFrom(
            _msgSender(),
            address(itemMarketplace),
            amountToLock
        );
        /**
         * @dev The params you see in the array are useful to create a unique hash to represent the ID of the item
         * @notice I've included the block.timestamp and the preorders counter to add a way to create pseudo-randomness on the hash
         */
        uint256[5] memory paramsToHash = [
            _newPreorder._idItem,
            _newPreorder._startDate,
            _newPreorder._endDate,
            preordersCounter.current(),
            block.timestamp
        ];
        bytes32 preorderID = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(paramsToHash));
        preordersCounter.increment();

        ItemMarketplaceLib.Preorder memory newPreorder = ItemMarketplaceLib
            .Preorder(
                itemToBorrow.owner,
                _msgSender(),
                block.timestamp,
                _newPreorder._idItem,
                _newPreorder._startDate,
                _newPreorder._endDate,
                amountToLock,
                preorderID,
                ItemMarketplaceLib.PreorderStatus.PENDING
            );
        preordersByID[preorderID] = newPreorder;

        emit PreorderCreated(
            itemToBorrow.owner,
            _msgSender(),
            preorderID,
            _newPreorder._idItem,
            _newPreorder._startDate,
            _newPreorder._endDate
        );
    }
```

This is a strange problem because I wrote a lot of tests for this contract and all of them are passing. When I invoke this function from the dapp it gives me this problem.
If you need anything else please let me know I'll provide it as soon as I can.
This is the code I'm using to invoke the function from my frontend.

```js
export const createPreorder = async (
    web3: Web3,
    id: number,
    startDate: number,
    endDate: number,
    hash: string,
    signature: string,
    from: string,
    symbolOfCoinUsed: string,
    price: number,
    caution: number,
) => {
    console.log(id, startDate, endDate, hash, signature);
    try {
        let coin: string;
        const calendarInstance = getCalendarInstance(web3);
        const tokenFactoryInstance = getTokenFactoryInstance(web3);
        if (calendarInstance == null) {
            console.error('calendar instance is null in createPreorder');
            throw new Error('Calendar instance is undefined');
        }
        const preorderRequest = {
            _idItem: id,
            _startDate: startDate,
            _endDate: endDate,
            _hash: hash,
            _signature: signature
        }
        coin = await tokenFactoryInstance
            .methods
            .getToken(symbolOfCoinUsed)
            .call({ from: from });
        const address = coin[0];
        const days = Math.ceil((endDate - startDate) / 60 / 60 / 24);
        const tokenTemplateInstance = getTokenInstance(web3, address);
        const total = parseFloat(caution.toString()) + (parseFloat(price.toString()) * days);
        console.log(`How many days preorder: ${days}. Price: ${total}`);
        console.log(preorderRequest);
        await tokenTemplateInstance
            .methods
            .approve(config.smartContracts.CALENDAR_ADDRESS, total)
            .send({ from: from, gasPrice: '0' })
        console.log(`Approved. ${from}`);
        const trx = await calendarInstance
            .methods
            .createPreorder(preorderRequest)
            .send({ from: from, gasPrice: '0' })
        console.log(`Preorder created`);
        console.log(trx);
    } catch (e: any) {
        console.error(e);
        if (e.message.includes('whitelist')) {
            throw new Error('This marketplace must be whitelisted');
        } else if (e.message.includes('invalid')) {
            throw new Error('Signature invalid, signer is not the owner');
        }
    }
}
```

I can't wrap my head around this, I've tried everything now.

Comment: Difficult to wrap my head around this too. What I would do: `emit Log("arrived here, still alive")` at least you'll know which line it breaks. You can also step into the execution flow with you favourite debugger (Remix, VS Code) and try to pinpoint the error.

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions. Another developer suggested to me to use Tenderly as debugger. I’ll try it out

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found my answer.
An address wasn’t set in my contract.